# Where is 'addtocart' for configurable products?

Tags: php, magento

Currently, when a product is out of stock, the 'addtocart' block disappears, but I want to change that so instead, it still displays the 'addtocart' block, but instead of the actual 'add to basket' button, it displays some text explaining that the product is out of stock.

I have managed to get this to work on simple products by taking

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
```

out of the

```
if ($_product->isSaleable())
```

section, and editing the 'addtocart' block so that if the product isn't saleable it displays the required text instead of the 'add to basket' button.

My issue is, for configurable products, whatever code dictates whether or not the 'addtocart' block is displayed isn't particularly obvious, I have looked all over view.phtml and load of other files, and grep'd through the entire directory, but the section I have already altered for simple products is the only one that shows up (in view.phtml)...

Any ideas?

Comment: This piece of code isn't going to help you.. More code..

Comment: Turn on template path hints and you should find the template: http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-turning-on-template-path-hints/

Comment: I had a look at the template path hints already, for a simple product addtocart.phtml is on its own (well, compared to the configurable anyway), whereas for a configurable product it's nestled within 'catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml', which has nothing useful in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was much simpler than I thought, in the 'view.phtml' file there were two sections of code:

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()): ?>
     <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Which grabs 'container2' if the product is BOTH a configurable product '$this->hasOptions()' AND is saleable.  Container2 has the block for displaying configurable options, related products (but just for configurable products, the line of code above this code displays the related products for simple products), and the addtocart block.  Below this code I had:

```
<?php if (!$this->hasOptions()): ?>
     <div class="add-to-box">
     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
     <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
          <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl = $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Which displays the addtocart block if the product is a simple product 'if (!$this->hasOptions()'.  I had to add the following bit of code as there was nothing which told the server what to do if the product was configurable but NOT saleable:

```
<?php if (!$_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()){ ?>
     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I'm fairly new to php so that was probably pretty obvious for a lot of people, but I managed to miss it for a good week or so (lucky this isn't my full time job!), hopefully this helps others!

Answer (score 0):

it's the same code (`if ($_product->isSaleable())`) but in the file `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is the file I have already edited, which has made it work for simple products, still no luck for configurable ones!

Comment: what is your Magento version?

Comment: 1.6.2.0, but not sure if it's Magento Go or whatever, how do I see that?